# Can someone explain Fetch APIs in detail?

Tags: javascript

Whats the use of Fetch API and what are promises and responses? I heard it is just used for fetching or extracting the data from the server.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API and the link on the left https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 3):

You should check this page,
It is very clear

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API